# Java FX Canvas doesn't show until complete

Tags: java, multithreading, canvas, javafx

I want to create a java FX application that draws lines on a Canvas one step at a time, with a noticable time between line segments. In the below application I have what I imagined would draw a diagonal line, stall a second and then draw the next diagonal line. Instead, the FX window pops up blank, waits 2 seconds, and then shows the two diagonal lines at the same time. How do I achieve the effect I am looking for? Is `javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas` not the right object to be using?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class FrameCanvas extends Application{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
  }
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception{
    ////////////////////Basic FX stuff
    Canvas theCanvas = new Canvas(900,900);
    StackPane theLayout = new StackPane();
    theLayout.getChildren().add(theCanvas);
    Scene theScene = new Scene(theLayout,900,900);
    primaryStage.setScene(theScene);
    primaryStage.show();
    ///////////////////////
    /////Drawing an X
    ///////////////////////
    GraphicsContext gc = theCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    gc.strokeLine(0,0,200,200);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    gc.strokeLine(200,0,0,200);
    /////////////////////////////
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't block (e.g. `Thread.sleep(...)`) the FX Application Thread. That thread is responsible for rendering the scene, so you will prevent any updates from being rendered.

Instead, use an animation for functionality like this (after all, an animation is really what you're creating here):

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception{
    ////////////////////Basic FX stuff
    Canvas theCanvas = new Canvas(900,900);
    StackPane theLayout = new StackPane();
    theLayout.getChildren().add(theCanvas);
    Scene theScene = new Scene(theLayout,900,900);
    primaryStage.setScene(theScene);
    primaryStage.show();
    ///////////////////////
    /////Drawing an X
    ///////////////////////
    GraphicsContext gc = theCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> gc.strokeLine(0,0,200,200)),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), e -> gc.strokeLine(200,0,0,200))
    );
    timeline.play();
    /////////////////////////////
}
```

Comment: how can I do this with a key pressed event handler so that whenever I press the space bar, the next line is drawn?

Comment: Put the data for the lines in a list. In the handler remove the first element of the list and draw a line with it.